# WCF Service Reference Error in WIndows Service

Tags: wcf, service, reference

I have a windows service with a base namespace of XXXX. I have a number of WCF services with a base namespace of WebServices. These are hosted in IIS.

When I add one of the WCF services (DataManagement) as a service reference to my windows service, I get the following errors when I build the service:

```
Error   162 The type name 'WebServices' does not exist in the type 'XXXX.XXXX'   
Reference.cs    Line 200    Col 61  

Error   163 The type name 'WebServices' does not exist in the type 'XXXX.XXXX'   
Reference.cs    Line 205    Col 94  

Error   164 The type name 'WebServices' does not exist in the type 'XXXX.XXXX'   
Reference.cs    Line 205    Col 134
```

Reference.cs is an automatically generated file, The lines of code created are:

Error 1:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IDataManagementChannel : XXXX.WebServices.IDataManagement, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}
```

Errors 2 & 3:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class DataManagementClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<XXXX.WebServices.IDataManagement>, XXXX.WebServices.IDataManagement {
```

I have been struggling to resolve these without much success. None of the suggestions I have found that appear to be related to this issue work for me. There was one issue with the same problem, but there were no answers. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the default namespace for your Windows Service? And do you possibly have any types in that namespace that are named the same as  XXXX in the XXXX.WebServices namespace?

Comment: Doesn't really matter what the namespace is, the definition errors are occurring on statements in Reference.cs that are defining the WCF service, and no, there are no types in the webservices namespace with the same name as types in the XXXX namespace. I did find one other person that posted on SO with the exact same error about 2 years ago, and they had no replies to their issue.

Comment: To clarify I'm not suggesting a that there is a type in both namespaces but rather a type name that matches the XXXX part of your namespace. Just to rule out a type name and namespace clash, could you edit your Reference.cs and change `XXXX.WebServices.IDataManagement` to `global::XXXX.WebServices.IDataManagement` and see if the compiler does not report that as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain your issue is as demonstrated by the following code

```
namespace XXXX
{
    class XXXX
    {
    }
}

namespace XXXX.WebServices
{
    class A
    {
    }

    class B : XXXX.WebServices.A // compiler error : CS0426 The type name 'WebServices' does not exist in the type 'XXXX'
    { 
    }
}
```

The compiler is attempting to find a nested type within the class `XXXX` called `WebServices` and not the `XXXX.WebServices` namespace hence the error "*does not exist in the **type***".

You can be explicit about the fact that you're referring to a namespace by prefixing the namespace with `global::`. It's not ideal to do this on a generated file like Reference.cs. If possible maybe consider generating your proxy in a different namespace.

See the help for compiler error CS0426 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f45d8e3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but in case someone stumbles upon this...

Steps to reproduce:

Create a windows service project "TestService".
Rename the Service1 class to TestService.

Compile - it works.

Add reference to a WCF service.

Compile - it no longer works.

error CS0426: The type name 'SomeWCFService' does not exist in the type 'TestService'

Solution: Change the name of the TestService class to something else, as it conflicts with the TestService namespace.